# Cannot Update user meta in custom field

Tags: users, user-meta

I have field to change user meta but update user meta does not change

```
add_action('user_register', 'save_extra_fields_country_institution_user_form');
add_action('profile_update', 'save_extra_fields_country_institution_user_form');
add_action('edit_user_profile', 'save_extra_fields_country_institution_user_form' );
    function save_extra_fields_country_institution_user_form($user_id){
        # again do this only if you can
        if(!current_user_can('manage_options') || !current_user_can( 'edit_user' ))
            return false;

        # save my custom field
        update_user_meta($user_id, 'verifier_assign_country', $_POST['country-verifier']);
        update_user_meta($user_id, 'verifier_assign_institution', $_POST['institution-verifier']);
        update_user_meta($user_id, 'verifier_price', $_POST['user_price']);

    }
```

Comment: Have you confirmed that this data is in the $_POST global? Add `print_r($_POST); die();` as the first line of your function and see what it says.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome,  either use edit_user_profile_update which is passed user_id

```
add_action('edit_user_profile_update', 'save_extra_fields_country_institution_user_form' );
    function save_extra_fields_country_institution_user_form($user_id){
        # again do this only if you can
        if(!current_user_can('manage_options') || !current_user_can( 'edit_user' ))
           return false;
        # save my custom field
        $result = update_user_meta($user_id, 'verifier_assign_country', 'test3');
    }
```

OR 
when I tested on 'edit_user_profile', the whole user object is being passed, not just the user id, so use:

```
function save_extra_fields_country_institution_user_form($user){
    # again do this only if you can
    if(!current_user_can('manage_options') || !current_user_can( 'edit_user' ))
       return false;
    # save my custom field
    $result = update_user_meta($user->ID, 'verifier_assign_country', 'test');
}
```

However https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/edit_user_profile  is more aimed at adding fields to screen, so I think what you want is 'edit_user_profile_update'

Comment: A good way to debug things like this is check everything: ie whether the action is firing, what you are being passed, any conditional logic and what is being returned by any function calls.  In this case adding something like error_log('Just in '.print_r($user_id, true));  revealed that user_id was actually user object.    It can also help to look at the actual code.   https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.9.8/src//wp-admin/user-edit.php#L141  showed me that if we wanted to do it only on update, then edit_user_profile_update was better.